# How to update table based on the values in other columns

Tags: sql, sybase

Here is a sample below,  I want to update AvailableAmt column based on the amount entered on UI.

[image]

**Requirement**

Update the value from the last row to the first row,

1. If entered 500 on UI, then the table will be like
   [image]
2. If entered 1000 on UI, then the table will be like
   [image]

Thank you for your help in advance !

Comment: I don't see the logic behind your updates, why is 500 removed from row 4 in the first example and why is 500 removed from row 3 in the second example?

Comment: It because the total amount on the 4th row is 500,  the total  amount on the 3rd row is 1000,     I have entered 1000 on UI,   so i can only reduce 500 on the 4th row,  and another 500 should be reduced from the 3rd row.

Comment: The same as if i entered 1500 on UI,  then the 4th row and the 3rd row are all 0 .

Comment: So it's like you want to subtract the entered amount from the remaining AvailableAmt in descending Row per Group ?  What if it goes negative?

Comment: So the second example is not after the first example but starting from the top sample?

Comment: Yes,  2 different scenarios.  Sorry not clear in the post.

Comment: It can not be negative. this will be handled on another part.  We can ignore this  here.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how this can be done in a simple SQL query since to me it looks like you need a loop here where you subtract the amount from TotalAmount from smallest to largest while amount > 0. Probably need a function for this based on using a db cursor.

Comment: so will you reduce lowest values first or oldest records first?

Comment: will sort by total amount, and then reduce from lowest .   Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't test it on a Sybase somewhere.
But in theory something like this might work:

```
DECLARE @Group VARCHAR(8) = 'a';
DECLARE @Amount INT = 1100;

UPDATE t
SET t.AvailableAmt = 
  CASE 
  WHEN q.PrevRemain > 0 AND t.AvailableAmt <= q.PrevRemain THEN 0
  WHEN q.PrevRemain > 0 THEN t.AvailableAmt - q.PrevRemain
  ELSE t.AvailableAmt
  END
FROM YourTable t
JOIN
(
    select [Group], [Row], 
     @Amount-(SUM(AvailableAmt) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY AvailableAmt, [Row] desc) - AvailableAmt) as PrevRemain
    from YourTable
    where AvailableAmt > 0
      and [Group] = @Group
) AS q
ON (q.[Group] = t.[Group] and q.[Row] = t.[Row]);
```

For a Sybase flavor that doesn't support the window function of SUM, something like this might work.

```
DECLARE @Group VARCHAR(8) = 'a';
DECLARE @Amount INT = 1200;

UPDATE t
SET t.AvailableAmt = 
  CASE 
  WHEN q.PrevRemain > 0 AND t.AvailableAmt <= q.PrevRemain THEN 0
  WHEN q.PrevRemain > 0 THEN t.AvailableAmt - q.PrevRemain
  ELSE t.AvailableAmt
  END
FROM YourTable t
JOIN
(
    select t1.[Group], t1.[Row], 
     @Amount - (SUM(t2.AvailableAmt)-t1.AvailableAmt) as PrevRemain
    from YourTable t1
    left join YourTable t2 on (t2.[Group] = t1.[Group]  and t2.AvailableAmt <= t1.AvailableAmt and t2.[Row] >= t1.[Row])
    where t1.AvailableAmt > 0
      and t1.[Group] = @Group
    group by t1.[Group], t1.[Row], t1.AvailableAmt
) AS q 
ON (q.[Group] = t.[Group] and q.[Row] = t.[Row]);
```

Comment: Since Sybase and SQL Server shares vanilla T-SQL, query tests good: https://rextester.com/ZRKQ37096.

Comment: Depending on which flavour of Sybase over() and partition() functions won't work as above.

Comment: Thank you, it is a good sample, even OLAP functions are not supported in ASE. But its really give me a good hint to finish the task.